Unable to send POST request to Google Apps Script Web App
I am using a Service Account with domain-wide delegation and have set the necessary OAuth scopes for the script. However, despite these efforts, I consistently receive a 401 Unauthorized error when the trigger is invoked.
Verified that the Service Account has been granted the required permissions and scopes. Also used Google Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub. These tools are configured to trigger my deployed Google Apps Script web app's doPost method every 5 minutes.
Confirmed that the deployed Google Apps Script web app is accessible via its public URL and responds correctly to authorized requests.
Attempted to pass the Authorization: Bearer header when making requests to the doPost method. Here is deployment details :
On the Script Editor:
Deployed as Web App + add-on.
Create new Project version
At Execute the app as, select "your account"
At Who has access to the app, select "Anyone within Organisation"
Click "Deploy"
Copy "Current web app URL"
Click "OK"
got the deployed web app url and deploymentid.
Now I have published connector with google workspace marketplace sdk with the deployed deploymentid. But when checked webapp url even on postman getting response as 401 unauthorized.
I would appreciate specific technical guidance or code snippets that can help resolve the 401 Unauthorized issue or provide an alternative approach for achieving frequent triggers(every 5 minutes).

Review " Taking advantage of webapps". See tag info page for  more details.

I also want to check, if what is the current Delopyment Settings.

@Babanana, here is deployment setting:
I have deployed as  web app + add-on
Execute as : me
Who has access : Anyone within Organisation
as I need to select web app +add-on beacuse web app provide me url for external access and add-on is for building an add-on for Gmail(connector).

I have very limited information with your current project, however I am experiencing the same thing before with "Anyone within Organisation" which causes some problems with authentication. If you change it to Anyone who has a Google Account it fixes it.

Basically I am triggering my web app from external scheduler job via service account. So in my service account I have generated json key which I am using to authenticate external request from scheduler job.

@Babanana, I cannot change to "Anyone" as my requirement(connector) is meant for organisation members only. I need who has access to stick to "Anyone within Organisation" that's why I am using service account with enabled domain-wide delegation and required oauth scopes to authenticate web app via this service account.

Can anyone guide me when I am using service account json key to authenticate web app with service account (enabled domain-wide delegation) getting this error which states that "The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent."

Consider asking new questions for new errors: it seems domain wide delegation is not set by admin. For this, Have you reviewed  the first link I posted?

@TheMaster I have gone through the link you have given. Its really helpful. Thanks alot.
